# CollectionAssert.AreEqual fails when compare list return form wcf service

Tags: wcf, unit-testing

below code fails because object in actual collection has ExtensionData field is "System.Runtime.Serialization.ExtensionDataObject" but object in expected list is null. is that possible skip test this field?

```
var expected = new List(<ServiceReference1.Order>)();
var client = ServiceReference1.OrderServiceClient();
var actual = client.GetOrder();
CollectionAssert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on your unit testing framework you can tell the test runner to ignore tests.

For example, mstest provides the `[Ignore]` attribute.

HOWEVER, the normal reaction to a failed test is not to ignore it. The test was obviously written for a reason. Normally it means that your change has broken something that used to work. However, under certain conditions the test may simply be invalid and if this is the case it should be removed and not just ignored.